# Using user email address as "From Name" and domain email as sender in contact forms?

Tags: email, spam, forms, spam-prevention, contact-page

We have a contact form with an email address field.

Let's say `user@yahoo.com` will send an email using our contact form.

When it's submitted this is what the headers would look like:

```
From: "user@yahoo.com" <noreply@ourdomain.com>
Reply-To: user@yahoo.com
```

This seems to pass SPF, DKIM, DMARC, which is my goal.

My concern is, this somewhat spoofs the From Name and From Email. Is this an acceptable practice?

Comment: Why are you adding the noreply@ part of the header?  Why not just make it be from user@yahoo.com?

Comment: @Steve that will not pass SPF, DKIM, DMARC as that implies that the message was sent from `@yahoo.com` even if it's technically not because the real server where the message is coming from is from `@ourdomain.com`

Comment: If at all possible you should use the domain name to respond to anything coming in through your contact form. That is the professional and legitimate way to do it.

Comment: @MichaelMoriarty True but that's not really the issue here.

Comment: Question was, "My concern is, this somewhat spoofs the From Name and From Email. Is this an acceptable practice?" Answer: "No, it is not acceptable practice."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's an acceptable practice. You could also append the users name and e-mail to the subject line or content if you want that information to be more visible to the recipient.